# Project CRS not being respected by QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, pyqgis, qgis-3

I have a button in a QGIS (3.4.1) plugin that should: create a new project; set it's CRS to `EPSG:4326'`, then import various maps.

However, when I run it for the first time after QGIS has loaded, the maps are show with their own CRS of `EPSG:3857`(confirmed in the bottom right of the GUI).  If I click the button a second time/**run the code again**, the maps are shown in the intended  CRS of `EPSG:4326` (again, confirmed in the bottom right).

The minimum code I can find to replicate the behavior is below:

```
    # Create new project
    iface.newProject(promptToSaveFlag=False)
    project = QgsProject.instance()

    # Create map tile layer (which by default uses EPSG:3857)
    map_uri = 'type=xyz&url=http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer(map_uri, 'openstreetmap.org', 'wms')
    if raster_layer.isValid():
        project.addMapLayer(raster_layer)

    # Set CRS to EPSG:4326
    project.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'))
```

Copy/pasting into the Python console seems to have the same results (i.e. first time after QGIS has loaded it doesn't work, second time it does).

Is this a bug in QGIS?

Can anyone propose a workaround?

Comment: Very helpful on both the question and answer sides, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** So it turns out using `QApplication.instance().processEvents()` could well be [dangerous](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19311#note-3) (and quite possibly [evil!](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255777/plugin-crashes-qgis-2-18-if-running-simuntaneously-with-python-console/257016#257016))

It seems using [`QTimer.singleShot()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot) is a better approach.

As such, I adopted my code below, which now works as expected.

```
def reset_and_load()
    # Create new project
    iface.newProject(promptToSaveFlag=False)
    project = QgsProject.instance()

    # Create map tile layer (which by default uses EPSG:3857)
    map_uri = 'type=xyz&url=http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer(map_uri, 'openstreetmap.org', 'wms')
    if raster_layer.isValid():
        project.addMapLayer(raster_layer)

    # Call QTimer with 10ms delay (adjust to suit) to set CRS
    QTimer.singleShot(10, set_project_crs)


def set_project_crs():
    # Set CRS to EPSG:4326
    QgsProject.instance().setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'))
```

For further reading see also the GIS answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245840/wait-for-canvas-to-finish-rendering-before-saving-image/246627#246627), and [comments here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94477/how-to-use-threads-in-pyqgis-mainly-to-keep-ui-active/94490#94490).

---

**Warning: Answer/code below is being left because it works, though could be dangerous - see edit above**

Thanks to the related section, I came across [@Kezhas answer here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/273821/106634) - who seemed to be <s>suffering</s> experiencing the same issue as me.

Essentially a `QApplication.instance().processEvents()` is required after adding the layer (and before setting the CRS), as follows:

```
# Create new project
iface.newProject(promptToSaveFlag=False)
project = QgsProject.instance()

# Create map tile layer (which by default uses EPSG:3857)
map_uri = 'type=xyz&url=http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer(map_uri, 'openstreetmap.org', 'wms')
if raster_layer.isValid():
    project.addMapLayer(raster_layer)

# Process events before setting CRS - Use at own risk (see above)!
QApplication.instance().processEvents()

# Set CRS to EPSG:4326
project.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'))
```